# Checkboxes uncheck when list updates - Android

Tags: android, checkbox, scroll, addition, unchecked

I have defined a task, which is just the a checkbox and a text together.

I also have a ListView of tasks that show correctly.

The problem is, when I scroll the list or when I try to add a new element to my list, all the checkboxes uncheck, but the text stays the same.

Here's what I have for getView in my TaskAdapter :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Task task = getItem(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.box);
    textView.setText(task.getDescription());
    checkBox.setActivated(task.getBox());
    return convertView;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help :D

Comment: use  checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                task.setBox(isChecked);
            }
        });

Comment: @asim. You forgot to tell how OP can determine the used `task` for the clicked item. As he needs a `position` for that.

Comment: @asim Thanks a lot, it worked when I used this to change the value in my list

Answer (score 2):

**task.getBox()** function returns false. That is the problem. Please check that area.

Comment: Even if i write setActivated(true), my boxes are still unchecked

Answer (score 0):

`checkBox.setActivated(task.getBox());` is used to activate/deactivate checkbox.

use `checkBox.setChecked(task.getBox());` to set checked/unchecked.